# Device registration (using DPS) and Device to IOT Hub Communication without SDK

Tags: x509certificate, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Need pointers on how to do device registration using Azure DPS (x509 cert) and communicate to IOT hub without using azure SDK libraries.

Is it possible via MQTT? any server (iot hun/DPS) listening to client who can send MQTT messages without using azure SDK? if yes any format on how to send request to register device using X509 certificate to azure DPS and then send messages/file upload to azure IOT Hub?

We need to implement this requirement in C language platform if not possible then C#.

Have already tried with REST API however I'm looking for MQTT option to archive this requirement

Thank,
Bhupal

Comment: why not use SDK? As with SDK, you can use MQTT easy.

Comment: Our devices software is on C language platform (Ingenico Telium 2 OS), considering the C SDK for IOT implementation we cannot use it because the Azure C SDK uses dynamic memory allocation and pthread which we dont support in our application. the dynamic memory allocation leads to memory fragmentation in our devices.

I'm looking for doing this using MQTT client. mainly we want to do this in C Language but as I didnt get any pointers in C yet I'm trying to do this in C# first and if successful I will replicate same on C platform.

Thanks,
Bhupal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/660) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly) you can find how to connect with IoT Hub via MQTT directly.

Comment: Thanks Kgalic. I have referred both the documentation/conversation. I managed to achieve sending message to IOT Hub using paho MQTT, I'm not sure whether device registration using azure DPS is possible with MQTT or not? also SDK does have option to upload files to IOT Hub however MQTT library does not have provision to send files to topic (iot hub) which is what I'm looking for specifically.

Comment: Well, that is the different question :) The dps supports MQTT for sure, but I haven't tried without sdk. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/about-iot-dps
Can you please mark the answer as correct if it was helpful :) thanks